# How can I optimize this indexing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, indexing

### My Questions

- Is there anyway that I can speed up this calculation?
- Is there a better algorithm or implementation that I can be use to calculate the same values?

### Describing the algorithm

I have a complex indexing problem that I'm struggling to solve in an efficient way.

The goal is to calculate the matrix `w_prime` using values a combination of values from the equally sized matrices `w`, `dY`, and `dX`.

The value of `w_prime(i,j)` is calculated as `mean( w( indY & indX ) )`, where `indY` and `indX` are the indices of `dY` and `dX` that are equal to `i` and `j` respectively.

Here's a simple implementation in matlab of an algorithm to compute `w_prime`:

```
for i = 1:size(w_prime,1)
  indY = dY == i;
  for j = 1:size(w_prime,2)
    indX = dX == j; 
    w_prime(ind) = mean( w( indY & indX ) );
  end
end
```

### Performance Problems

This implementation is sufficient in example case below; however, in my actual use case `w`, `dY`, `dX` are ~`3000x3000` and `w_prime` is ~`60X900`.  Meaning that each index calculation is happening on a ~9 million elements. Needless this implementation is too slow to be usable. Additionally I'll need to run this code a few dozen times.

### Example Calculation

If I want to compute `w(1,1)`

- Find the indices of `dY` that equal 1, save as `indY`
- Find the indices of `dX` that equal 1, save as `indX`

[image]

- Find intersection of `indY` and `indX` save as `ind`

[image]

- Save the  `mean( w(ind) )`  to `w_prime(1,1)`

[image]

### General Problem Description

I have a set points defined by two vectors `X`, and `T`, both are 1XN where N is ~3000. Additionally the values of X and T are integers bound by the intervals (1 60) and (1 900) respectively.

The matrices `dX` and `dT`, are simply distance matrices, meaning that they contain the pairwise distances between the points. Ie `dx(i,j)` is equal `abs( x(i) - x(j) )`.

They are calculated using: `dx = pdist(x);`

The matrix `w` can be thought of as a weight matrix that describes how much influence one point has on another.

The purpose of calculating `w_prime(a,b)` is to determine the average weight between the sub-set of points that are separated by `a` in the `X` dimension and `b` in the `T` dimension.

This can be expressed as follows:

[image]

Comment: Hi there! I was wondering if you could provide a more general description of your problem requiring the use of this computation (eg. pathfinding - needing to compute new position, etc..). Maybe a better algorithm as a total can be suggested?

Comment: haha wow! ok, definitely not the easy problem I was hoping for. I'll try and come back to this when I'm reunited with my whiteboard lol hopefully someone else can help you in the interim. Purely out of curiosity now, why would you do this? What general purpose would finding the average influence serve? I'm guessing some sort of data correlation??

Comment: Every problem should be described with this amount of detail and precision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is straightforward with [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
nx = max(dX(:));
ny = max(dY(:));

w_prime = accumarray([dX(:),dY(:)],w(:),[nx,ny],@mean,NaN)
```

The output will be a `nx`-by-`ny` sized array with NaNs wherever there was no corresponding pair of indices. If you're sure that there will be a full complement of indices all the time, you can simplify the above calculation to

```
w_prime = accumarray([dX(:),dY(:)],w(:),[],@mean)
```

So, what does accumarray do? It looks at the rows of `[dX(:),dY(:)]`. Each row gives the `(i,j)` coordinate pair in `w_prime` to which the row contributes. For all pairs `(1,1)`, it applies the function (`@mean`) to the corresponding entries in `w(:)`, and writes the output into `w_prime(1,1)`.

Comment: I want to make babies with the creators of MATLAB